# Installation Hangs after "Successfully installed Python 2.7" while installing production windows-build-tools

Tags: python, node.js, node-pty, windows-build-tools

Trying to install windows-build-tools using the following command

```
npm install -g --production windows-build-tools
```

But seems it hangs after installing python2.7. I have waited for almost 30 minutes but not moving forward. Any solution??

> ---------- Visual Studio Build Tools ---------- [021C:1D04][2021-03-24T19:18:58]i000: MUX:  Next Source: Web,
> Attempted: 1, Limit:3 [021C:1D04][2021-03-24T19:18:58]i000: MUX:
> Source retrieved: Web [021C:1D04][2021-03-24T19:18:58]i000: MUX:
> Package:VC_CRT_ARM_Desktop,
> PayloadId:cab41658CA9BF562A2EE31DDCEC6EE7ABBF Url:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14rel&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=25420.01&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=862E760128D21CD3AB6F447CFCCFAF6A928536F0,
> Attempting count: 1 [021C:1D04][2021-03-24T19:18:58]i000: MUX:
> Existing last unconfirmed source: Web
> [021C:1D04][2021-03-24T19:18:58]i338: Acquiring package:
> VC_CRT_ARM_Desktop, payload: cab41658CA9BF562A2EE31DDCEC6EE7ABBF,
> download from:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14rel&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=25420.01&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=862E760128D21CD3AB6F447CFCCFAF6A928536F0
> ------------------- Python -------------------- Successfully installed Python 2.7

[image]

Comment: It takes a long time and most of the times it fails but frankly I have switched into Linux and problems are solved...

Comment: use wsl-2 for windows

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It should be a npm package bug of windows-build-tools.

Step 1: Be sure you installed Visual Studio Code

Step 2: Search %temp% under window search bar (Copy `%temp%` then press windows button + Ctrl V)

[image]

Step 3: Create 'dd_client_.log.txt' and enter 'Closing installer. Return code: 3010.'

[image]

Now you should be able to finish the whole process with `npm install --global windows-build-tools`

[image]

Comment: Still relevant till this day. I've tried multiple solutions and this one actually helped, would gladly mark it as an answer if I could.

Comment: This worked. This should be the answer

Comment: This worked for me, after creating the file the process stopped which was running for more than 5-6 hours.