# Error: TypeError: 'process.env' only accepts a configurable whileinstall windows-build-tools

Tags: javascript, node.js, .net, angular, npm

Downloading installers failed. Error: TypeError: 'process.env' only accepts a configurable, writable, and enumerable data descriptor.

I have run this command npm install --global windows-build-tools

Node version : v18.12.0
NPM version : 8.19

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.
First I tried to do `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@4.0.0`  but didn't work then `npm config set msvs_version 2022` but still didn't work.

Finally I tried to download node version 17.9.1 and retried the command and it worked!!

So here are the steps:

Step 1: uninstall Node version 18.12 and install version [17.9.1](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/node-v17.9.1-x64.msi)

Step 2: Search %temp% under window search bar (Copy %temp% then press windows button + Ctrl V)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGaSg.png

Step 3: Create 'dd_client_.log.txt' and enter 'Closing installer. Return code: 3010.'
https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Mju.png

after that you should be able to finish the whole process with `npm install --global windows-build-tools`

big thanks to [seantsang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70377331/20353113)

Between I have no Idea if the technique of seantsang work directly when installing windows-build-tools with node.js version 18.12 .
If what I said didn't help, maybe try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72644081/20353113)

Comment: for those who might stumble on: _openssl_ [error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72636746/11750420)

Comment: Followed this exactly and got a new error `npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'`

Comment: this is the correct one .... thanks mate

Comment: Wow, this is magic! U saved me, after 5 days investiattion! Thank U Sir!

Comment: WHY DOES THIS WORK??? H O W ? 
thank you though, got a different unrelated error somewhere else now :^)

Answer (score 4):

When you downgrade to node v17 and run the command, it prints out a warning linking to [the windows-build-tools repo](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools), which tells you to use the official [Node.js for Windows installer](https://nodejs.org/en/download). There was a checkbox I'd skipped and forgotten about to install C++ build tools. It runs after the main node installer is done.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation when I tried to install a nodejs dependency using npm. In my case I downgraded to Node 17.9.1 (uninstalling the newer version before) and when the setup program went to [Tools for Native Modules section](https://i.imgur.com/i00Qzmb.png), I checked the toolbox.

Then I executed Nodejs Command Tool as administrator and put `npm install --global windows-build-tools`

Isn't necessary to use the Visual Studio Installer and check the Desktop development with C++. I did the same and didn't work for me.

I have Windows 11 22H2.