# Downloading installers failed. Error: TypeError: 'process.env' only accepts a configurable, writable, and enumerable data descriptor

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, node-gyp, windows-build-tools

I was facing errors when installing `better-sqlite3` so I googled and found I need windows build tools, so I ran `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` and got this error, I tried the only solution available for this [Error: TypeError: 'process.env' only accepts a configurable whileinstall windows-build-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74227892/error-typeerror-process-env-only-accepts-a-configurable-whileinstall-windows)

But didn't work so anyone can help me please
[image]

I was expecting to download windows build tools and ran the command but didnt run gave me an error